# how does the hover content of the first variable not display comments

Tags: visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

I use monaco-editor to write ts files. Before the first variable declaration, write a comment. How to not show comments when mouse hovers over first variable？

[image]

Like this, I want this [image]

Comment: I'm getting a sense that this is not possible from the fact that such settings typically contain `hover.documentation` in their names, and I don't see such a setting for JS/TS

Comment: when `a` is a function you would complain that you do not see the explanation/documentation of the function, if you don't want that text don't write that text

Comment: If that's a 3rd party lib then you cannot change the code. This is a valid question about how to suppress JSDoc text in the hover tooltip.